# How to convert an uploaded file (InMemoryUploadedFile) from pdf to jpeg in Django using wand?

Tags: django, python-3.x, file-upload, type-conversion, wand

I'm trying to convert a pdf file uploaded in Django to a jpg file. I would like to use the file directly in the InMemoryUploadedFile state.

I tried to use wand but without any success. 
Here is the code I wrote:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from wand.image import Image as wi

# Create your views here.
def readPDF(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        if uploaded_file.content_type == 'application/pdf':
            pdf = wi(filename=uploaded_file.name, resolution=300)
            pdfImage = pdf.convert("jpeg")
    return render(request, 'readPDF.html', {"pdf": pdfImage})
```

I tried different things like using uploaded_file.file or uploaded_file.name as the first argument for the wand image but without any success.`

I thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to pass `InMemoryUploadedFile` directly to Wand's constructor.

```py
uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
if uploaded_file.content_type == 'application/pdf':
    with wi(file=uploaded_file, resolution=300) as pdf:
        # ...
```

However, I wouldn't recommend attempting to convert PDF pages to JPEGs in a HTTP request. Best to write the document to storage, and have a background worker manage the slow / unsafe tasks.